# Can you query where contacts come from or add a filter to prevent deleted contacts from coming back?

Tags: delete

I have been monitoring my all contacts and it has been jumping 10000+ every day.  I doubt these are authentic contacts

Is it possible to somehow do a query of where these contacts are coming from?
Also is it possible to add a filter to a sych data extension to prevent contacts from coming in if they have been deleted>

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Salesforce queries do not retrieve deleted records unless [ALL ROWS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm) is used.

To retrieve **only deleted** contacts

```
SELECT Id, name, IsDeleted FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS
```

To Retrieve **non-Deleted** contacts only (add filter contion on isDeleted)

```
SELECT Id, name, IsDeleted FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = FALSE
```

Comment: I tried using this on Query Studio - does it not work? Gave an error saying "Error saving the Query field.Contact is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views."

Comment: Hey, Never tried Query Studio so not sure..

Comment: What are you using to use this queryt?  I tried in automation studio and it does not appear to work :(

Comment: My Apologies, I think i got it confused this is an apex query to retrieve data in salesforce instances... I believe you are trying the same in marketing cloud I am not sure how to do the same on MC 